# How can I easily generate an SAS token for azure blob container that includes the 't' permission

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

It is really easy to generate an SAS token using the azure portal. The problem is that it doesn't include all of the available permissions. Notably it is missing the 't' permission which is necessary to assign tags.

I have had a look through the documentation about generating a user delegation SAS for this using Powershell, but I dont have (and cant get) sufficient permissions. I can however generated an Account Key sas.

Can any on provide guidance on how this permission can be added to the SAS either in the portal or through Powershell?

Comment: What kind of SAS you're trying to generate - [Account SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) or [Service SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas)?

Comment: I am not too stressed about it. Just one that is easy and works. Whatever the GUI creates when you specify the 'Account Key' method is good. It works perfectly except for this permission issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating SAS using the **[Storage  Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)** .I tried this in my system

**1)** select the your storage account  **right click**  select the  **Get the shared access signature.**

[image]

**2)** You can select the **permission** you want to add  and
Click on **create**

[image]

**3)** A second **Shared Access Signature dialog** will then display that lists the blob container along with the **URL(Connection String) and QueryStrings** you can use to access the storage resource. Select Copy next to the URL you wish to copy to the clipboard

[image]

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs):

Comment: You are a god amongst men.